# Why is adding instances of scipy.sparse.dia_matrix so slow?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm writing a numerical code, where I'm using `scipy.sparse.dia_matrix`. My matrices are quite large (up to about 1000000 x 1000000), but very sparse. Sometimes tridiagonal, sometimes with a some more diagonals.

For various reasons, it is extremely convenient and clear from a coding point of view to just add together several of these matrices (of the same size, of course). However, I have found that adding these sparse matrices is very slow. The following example illustrates what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import diags, dia_matrix

N = 100000

M1 = diags(diagonals = [np.random.random(N-1), np.random.random(N), np.random.random(N-1)], offsets = [-1, 0, 1])
M2 = diags(diagonals = [np.random.random(N-1), np.random.random(N), np.random.random(N-1)], offsets = [-1, 0, 1])
M3 = diags(diagonals = [np.random.random(N-1), np.random.random(N), np.random.random(N-1)], offsets = [-1, 0, 1])

def simple_add():
    M = M1 + M2 + M3
    
def complicated_add():
    M_ = dia_matrix((N, N))
    for d in [-1, 0, 1]:
        M_.setdiag(M1.diagonal(d) + M2.diagonal(d) + M3.diagonal(d), d)

%timeit simple_add()

%timeit complicated_add()
```

The output of the timing is:

```
16.9 ms ± 730 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
959 µs ± 39.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I don't understand why adding the matrices together with the + operator is 17 times slower than creating an empty digagonal matrix and explicitly setting the diagonals. Is there anything I can do to speed this up? I would much prefer to keep the simpler expression with the + operator, as it's far more readable, but not at the expense of an order of magnitude increase in computational time.

**Update:**

I proposed a change in Scipy that would make addition of two instances of `dia_matrix` faster, and after a bit of discussion I submitted a pull request to Scipy, which has now been merged. So in the future, adding two instances of `dia_matrix` will no longer convert to `csr_matrix`.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/14004

Comment: The implementation of `_add_sparse(self, other)` is `return self.tocsr()._add_sparse(other)`. The extra time is to turn it into a CSR matrix (which has a C extension for addition).

Comment: Oh my! That explains the considerable overhead. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. By the way, does that mean I can "overload" the add operation in some way, to get the clean code that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `_add_sparse(self, other)` is return `self.tocsr()._add_sparse(other)`. The extra time is to turn it into a CSR matrix (which has a C extension for addition).

Could you create a sparse matrix that does what you want? Probably.

```
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix, isspmatrix_dia

class dia_matrix_adder(dia_matrix):

    def __add__(self, other):

        if not isspmatrix_dia(other):
            return super(dia_matrix_adder, self).__add__(other)

        M_ = dia_matrix((self.shape[0], self.shape[1]))

        for d in [-1, 0, 1]:
            M_.setdiag(self.diagonal(d) + other.diagonal(d), d)

        return M_
```

I would probably not do that and just write yourself a function:

```
def add_dia_matrix(*mats):

    if len(mats) == 1:
        return mats[0]

    M_ = dia_matrix((mats[0].shape[0], mats[0].shape[1]))

    for d in [-1, 0, 1]:
        M_diag = mats[0].diagonal(d).copy()

        for i in range(1, len(mats)):
            M_diag += mats[i].diagonal(d)

        M_.setdiag(M_diag, d)

    return M_
```

This should be as readable as a bunch of `+` without having to deal with a new class.

```
%timeit simple_add()
30.3 ms ± 218 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit complicated_add()
1.28 ms ± 2.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit add_dia_matrix(M1, M2, M3)
1.22 ms ± 4.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

`diags` makes a `dia_matrix` from the list of inputs:

```
In [84]: M=sparse.diags([np.arange(1,4),np.arange(1,5),np.arange(1,4)], offsets=[-1,0,1])
In [85]: M
Out[85]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [86]: M.offsets
Out[86]: array([-1,  0,  1], dtype=int32)
In [87]: M.data
Out[87]: 
array([[1., 2., 3., 0.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [0., 1., 2., 3.]])
```

The list of diagonals (different lengths) has been transformed into a 2 array, with offsets.  This is intended primarily as a input format.  Most, if not all, math is implemented in the `csr` format. And even there, matrix_multiplication is the relative strong point.  Element-wise math is distinctly inferior to `numpy` array equivalents.

```
In [89]: Mr=M.tocsr()
In [90]: Mr
Out[90]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [91]: Mr.data
Out[91]: array([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 4.])
In [92]: Mr.indices
Out[92]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [93]: Mr.indptr
Out[93]: array([ 0,  2,  5,  8, 10], dtype=int32)
```

The `dia` format suggests a faster addition, if the offsets and shape are all the same.

```
In [94]: M.data += M.data + M.data
In [95]: M.data
Out[95]: 
array([[ 3.,  6.,  9.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  9., 12.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9.]])
In [96]: M.A
Out[96]: 
array([[ 3.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  6.,  9.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  9., 12.]])
```

With any of the sparse formats, if the sparsity is the same for all arguments and output, you can often do math directly on the `data` attribute, leaving the implied 0's unchanged.